# Cognito forms prefill fails

Tags: cognitoforms

I'm attempting to prefill a field on a CognitoForms form.

```
Cognito.prefill({"CharityName": "FOo"});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uw4rdeta/

This code is straight from the docs (https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/65/data-integration/prefilling-a-form), and I have tried both the 'seamless' and iframe methods. Fields are not prefilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you could try like this

```
<script>     
     Cognito.prefill({"AboutYourCharity":{"CharityName": "FOo"}});
</script>
```

Comment: try this:<script>     Cognito.prefill({"AboutYourCharity":{"CharityName": "FOo"}});</script>

Comment: Thankyou Rajesh, this does indeed work +1 ... However, it does not work when triggered on a button click. https://jsfiddle.net/uw4rdeta/5/

Comment: on button click, you need to load the whole iframe

Comment: Got this working in the end using the 'seamless' method plus `Cognito.load("forms", { id: "9", entry: {"AboutYourCharity": {CharityName: ...` syntax NB INCLUDING section name. Thanks Rajesh.

Comment: What does `AboutYourCharity` refers to in your example?